# node.js readSync and stream return different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, readfile

I want to read file with stream to update UI progress bar. But after I start experimenting with [fs.createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) I noticed that I receive different results. For example:

```
var d = fs.readFileSync('file.bin', null);
console.log(d);
console.log(d.byteLength);
```

Returns in console:

> Buffer(188000)
>
> 188000

But this code:

```
var rd = fs.createReadStream('file.bin');
var data = '';
rd.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
rd.on("data", function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.length);
    data += chunk;
});
rd.on("end", function() {
    console.log('There will be no more data.');
    var buf = Buffer.from(data, null);
    console.log(buf)
    console.log(buf.byteLength)
});
```

Returns in console:

> Uint8Array(297684)
>
> 297684

Why stream returns `Uint8Array` instead of `Buffer` object and why they have different sizes

Comment: Both `fs.createReadStream()` and `Buffer.from()` allow you to specify the desired encoding.

Comment: Worth reading this https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray about buffers and Uint8Array.  A Uint8Array is a Buffer.

Comment: I the same result from each approach in Windows using Node.js v6.9.2. Both return a length of 188000 (from a binary file of length 188000).

Comment: @jfriend00 I need raw data

Comment: @jfriend00 but why it creates not Buffer class...

Comment: Did you read that link?  It is a Buffer object and can be used exactly like a Buffer object.